# How to improve accuracy of LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm trying to predict timeseries data by 'LSTM sequence to sequence' model.
I used keras.
What should I change in my model to increase accuracy?

- Input: past 4 time steps
- output: future 2 steps
- number of features: 5
- data dimensions:

  ```
  train_x (1308, 4, 5)
  train_y (1308, 2, 5)
  test_x (118, 4, 5)
  test_y (118, 2, 5)
  ```

Result : `[mse : 0.021793483835408241, accuracy : 0.54661016696590492]`

Model definition:

```
def fit_model(n_cells):
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(n_cells, input_shape=(4,5)))
    model.add(Dense(n_cells))
    model.add(RepeatVector(2))  
    model.add(LSTM(n_cells,  input_shape=(10,5), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5,  activation='linear')))  
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    hist=History()
    for i in range(100):
    hist=model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
    loss=model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
    print(loss)

cells = [150]
for value in cells:
    fit_model(value)
```

Comment: You seem to be performing regression, so accuracy does not make sense in that case.

Comment: Why accuracy doesn't matter when I'm performing regression?

Comment: Because accuracy only applies for classification (discrete outputs), so you can compare for equality. In regression you predict a continuous value, so if the target is 0.99 and your network predicts 1.0, then it is considered as misclassified. Thus accuracy makes no sense.

Comment: Oh thank you!!! :)